# Use number and phrase in a single custom slot for alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, alexa-slot

Is there a way to create a custom slot type which contains both a phrase and a number. Something like:

```
{
                "name": "mycustomslot",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "name": {
                            "value": "eating",
                            "synonyms": [
                                "eat something",
                                "are you eating",
                                "eat"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": {
                            "value": "drinking",
                            "synonyms": [
                                "drink something",
                                "drinking",
                                "drink",
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                    {
                        "name": {
                            "value": AMAZON.NUMBER,
                            "synonyms": []
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
```

So, I can get "eating" from utterances "eat something", "are you eating" etc. and a number on uttering a number from a single slot type.

Comment: What do you actually expect the user to say?

Comment: The user can either say "drink something", or say a number. If user says "drink something" I will receive the action as drinking and if the user says a number, I will receive just a number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this type: [AMAZON.SearchQuery](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#phrase-types)

This type can get all the phrase which user speaks.

Utterance: I eat **{query}** (with type of "query" is AMAZON.SearchQuery)

Speech: I eat **9 plates of meat**

=> The value handler will receive is something like this: { name: "query", value: "9 plates of meat"}